# Do I need to have Java installed on my local machine to run a website that uses JSP pages?

Tags: java, jsp

This is probably a stupid question but I know nothing about Java.  Did a quick google and found nothing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If "running a website" means serving it, then yes. If it means viewing the website, then no (unless it contains Java applets, but that's orthogonal to your question).

Comment: Is it really orthogonal? After all some freak could still create a JSP that contains an applet. Couldn't they?

Comment: @er4z0r: of course they can. That's what I mean by orthogonal: they can put in an applet regardless of whether the website is implemented in JSP or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to run locally a website that uses JSP pages, you'll need at least Java plus a servlet container : typically Tomcat or Jetty.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary, JSP is a **server** side technology that generally speaking responds to http requests with html (or images/css/javascript).

As long as you have a client in your machine that can send http requests and read the responses ( a web browser for example), you can perfectly use a JSP application.

The only case when you will need to have java runtime in your local machine, is if you are connecting to a page that includes an applet, java web start o javafx app.

Maybe you should comment if you are intending to SERVE the website from your local machine, or just connect from your local machine to a website in another server

Answer (score 2):

- To just visit the site on your machine does not require a JVM installed on your machine
- If you are running a server on your machine (which is serving the webpages) then you need JVM installed on your machine, and JDK to actually develop a JSP website project for compilation purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If the website only uses JSP (no webstart, no applets) then you do not need java since no java code is run on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Every jsp page is "compiled" into a .java file which then is compiled using the javac compiler into .class and then finally executed by the application server. 
So yes, you do not Java installed to run JSP -- and more specifically you will need JDK not just the JRE!